# ImageView not updated in ItemList

Tags: android

I am trying to update the  image inside ItemList, I am using the below method

This is how I am getting ImageView 'imgView' Object using the below methods -

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JSONParsingMainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email", "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(markedQuestion != null){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(markedQuestion);
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String questionid = c.getString("questionid");
                    System.out.println("Question No :" + i + "Question Id is :" + questionid);


                    Long itemId = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(Integer.parseInt(questionid));
                    System.out.println("Item Id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxasdasd" + itemId);


                    changedView = (CardView) getViewByPosition(Integer.parseInt(questionid),lv);
                    imgView = (ImageView) changedView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewstickId);
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mp.start();
                position++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

This code is not updating the cancel image in the list item, when I debug I am getting correct id (i.e. 'imageViewstickId' as shown in XML), but the image is not updating, nor giving any error

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
```

My XML code also -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewQuestionId"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingBottom="2dp"
         android:paddingTop="6dp"
         android:text="test"
         android:textColor="@color/gradientStart"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />


     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageViewstickId"
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

 </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/gradientStop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have tried everything modifying the code, etc. but nothing works for me
Any help shall be appreciated, thanks

Edits - (Added Debug screen Shot) Please check in debug window, CardViewId is same as XML ImageView id... Still not updating

[image]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/22625142/7064548

Comment: Use this picasso for set image of any type : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620522/7319704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be helpful for others to think this way -

I got Clue from this post - [how to know when listview is finished loading data on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626781/how-to-know-when-listview-is-finished-loading-data-on-android)

My data may be getting updated, but the list was not fully loaded and thats why the data is over writing. I used the following code , thanks for the actual user who posted the above answer

```
lv.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "list got updated, do what ever u want");


                    if(markedQuestion != null){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(markedQuestion);
                            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int x = 0; x < contacts.length(); x++) {
                                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(x);

                                String questionid = c.getString("questionid");
                                System.out.println("Question No :" + x + "Question Id is :" + questionid);


                                System.out.println(getResources());
                                changedView = (CardView) getViewByPosition(Integer.parseInt(questionid),lv);
                                imgView = (ImageView) changedView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewstickId);
                                //  imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
                                imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.cancel));

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
```

write:

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cancel));
```

Try it. Let's hope it works.

Comment: Umang..Could not work..listview is not updating imageview (added debug screen shot)

Comment: @Aman What is in the value of `context` What have you assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:
If you are in Activity then use this

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("cancel","drawable", getPackageName());
```

Or in Fragment

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("cancel","drawable", context.getPackageName());
 // "cancel" drawable resource name
 // "drawable" drawable directory
```

This will return the id of the drawable you want to access... then you can set the image in the imageview by doing the following

```
 imgView.setImageResource(id);
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two best solutions for that:-

1) Instead of using this

```
   imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
```

Use This Method:-

```
   imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cancel));
```

2)Using Glide Library
      https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Your id is correct still it is not updating then it might be a problem that your Resource file (R.java) is not updating try cleaning your project and then check.

If this not works you can also try following code:-

```
Resources resources = getResources();
imgView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.cancel));
```